# import image is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, import

I am trying to import an image in javascript but don't know why it not working infact it stop my whole javascript file from doing anything

```
import img from './image.png'
console.log(img)
```

It's not showing anything in console not even any type of error and if I write more code below it that also don't work.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info about your project? Are you using any kind of module bundler? Like Webpack for example?

Comment: You need a module bundler with a proper loader.